# Repeat letters within a string in Matlab

Tags: matlab

I would like to generate a string in Matlab that looks like

`"BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBCCCCCCCCCCCCCC"`

where `"B"` is repeated `m` times and `"C"` is repeated `n` times. Is there any function with inputs similar to `("B","C",n,m)` doing this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the function `repelem` to repeat the *characters* the wanted number of times.

```
str = 'BC' %This is character vector, NOT a string
n = 4; m = 3;
res = repelem(str,[n,m])

res =

    'BBBBCCC'
```

Answer (score 3):

`repmat` function works on char arrays, and concatenation operators too.
So:

```
copyfcn = @(B,C,n,m) [repmat(B,[1 n]) repmat(C,[1,m])];
copyfcn('B','C',8,4)

ans =

    'BBBBBBBCCCC'
```

If you want the output to be a string rather than a char array, you can just wrap it in the `string()` function.

```
copyfcn2 = @(B,C,n,m) string([repmat(B,[1 n]) repmat(C,[1,m])]);
copyfcn2('B','C',8,4)

ans = 

    "BBBBBBBBCCCC"
```

Answer (score 3):

You can make your own function using `repmat`:

```
>> f = @(a,b,n,m) [repmat(a, [1 m]) repmat(b, [1 m])];
>> f('B','C',12,14)

ans =

    'BBBBBBBBBBBBBBCCCCCCCCCCCCCC'
```